# JSOUP Parsing issue with android app

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup

I'm having trouble parsing data from this website http://hdh.ucsd.edu/mobile/dining/locationdetails.aspx?l=18 in order to get the hours of operation. Nothing shows up when I try this and I am not sure which part of the site to parse.

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements elements = document.select("div[class=labels]");
HOURS = elements.text();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following query -

```
Elements elements = document.select("#MainContent_regHours");
```

It is also a good practice to add a `user agent` string to match your browser, so you'll get the same page both at your mobile device and your PC.